# Изменить стиль каждого третьего элемента, начиная с четвертого через CSS

Tags: css

Я знаю и использую nth-child() на обычном уровне, но с этой задачей бьюсь уже неприлично долго. Есть список div'ов, можно считать, что их неограниченное количество.

Что требуется: через css задать стили элементам, находящимся на *4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, etc* месте. При этом это не должно затрагивать первый элемент в списке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  background: lightgray;
}

div:nth-child(3n+4) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

Comment: Нормальный способ